# how to remove my app's folder from galleries?

Tags: android

My app creates a folder, but strangely it appears in galleries.

Is there a way for the app to keep its folders "hidden" from galleries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can name your folder .Myfolder adding "." will make it invisible to the galleries